# AuraDefinitionBundle No APPLICATION named markup://

Tags: lightning, managed-package, aura

I'm facing yet another odd error when attempting to upload my managed package. It is throwing this

AuraDefinitionBundle - InitialLinkingApp No APPLICATION named markup://[namespace_redacted]:InitialLinkingApp found

That app definitely exists, and is in the package. Before this would only happen if we had a postInstall script defined but now it's doing it even without the script. We have confirmed that all test classes pass, all classes compile and code coverage is about 75% across the board. Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same issue today while releasing. I cannot pin point the fix to either of the two following changes but the upload went through after we:

- disabled lightning experience in the packaging org
- increased the api version of the affected components (in our case from 40.0 to 42.0)

Comment: I did open a case and they have confirmed it is an issue. Last I heard they were escalating to tier 3. Just out of curiosity, on the lightning component it's complaining about are you doing anything kind of non standard with your attributes? I'm starting to develop a hunch that it might not like this line in mine...

<aura:attribute name="InitialLinkingControllerWrapper" type="InitialLinkingController" />

Trying to make a class instance into a variable so all class properties are easily available, but maybe it doesn't like that. Is your package managed?

Comment: Nah, the component is really simple, no special attributes. And yes, it's a managed package.